# Capture WinKey shortcuts in Javascript

Tags: javascript, keyboard

I'm trying to pass to javascript some shortcuts with Winkey inside. For example:

- `ctrl + Winkey + e`,
- `ctrl + Winkey + s` etc.

The problem that I encounter is that when I click and hold `ctrl` then `Winkey` then `e`. And have the following code sample

```js
$("#dd").keydown(function (e){
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    if (e.metaKey && e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 69) { /*ctrl + winkey + e */
        console.log(e.keyCode);
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Focus on input to register keys:
<input id="dd" />
```

I see that the `onkeydown` captures `ctrl`, `Winkey`, and after pressing `e` it freezes (`e` is not captured nor any other click is captured as long as `ctrl` and `Winkey` are pressed). Is there some way to omit that behavior and capture the whole shortcut?

Comment: `it freezes` - what freezes?

Comment: e is 69 not 83, and what makes you think the winkey is the "metakey"? (oh, sorry, firefox doesn't consider the winkey as the metakey)

Comment: @JaromandaX e is not captured nor any other click is captured as long as ctrl and Winkey are pressed.

Comment: probably because the operating system doesn't "pass" any keystrokes to the in focus application once these keys are held (I think once the winkey is held, at least windows won't pass other keystrokes (aside from shift/ctrl/Alt) - the winkey after all belongs to windows :p